# Add number of days in Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to add `+1` if the date is `sunday`. Below code works for the rest dates. But when I pass `30 sept 2012` I gives me `1 Sept 2012` instead of `1 Oct 2012` in `dateMsg`. What is wrong with the code?. Please guide.  I guess I'l face same problem in all last date of the month.How to add 1 to whole date rather than just the day?

```
var monthName=convertMnthNoToName(freeLookEndDt.getMonth()+1);

    if (freeLookEndDt.getDay()==0) {

      var date=new Date(freeLookEndDt.getFullYear(),freeLookEndDt.getMonth(),
      freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1);
      var newmonthName=convertMnthNoToName(date.getMonth()+1);
      var dateMsg = date.getDate() + '-' + monthName + '-' + freeLookEndDt.getFullYear();

      document.forms[0].flEndDt.value=dateMsg;

    }
```

and convertMnthNoToName()

```
function convertMnthNoToName(val)
{
    if(val==01 || val==1)
    {
      val1="Jan";
    }
    if(val==02 || val==2)
    {
      val1="Feb";   
    }
    if(val==03 || val==3)
    {
      val1="Mar";   
    }
    if(val==04 || val==4)
    {
      val1="Apr";   
    }
    if(val==05 || val==5)
    {
      val1="May";   
    }
    if(val==06 || val==6)
    {
      val1="Jun";   
    }
    if(val==07 || val==7)
    {
      val1="Jul";   
    }
    if(val==08 || val==8)
    {
      val1="Aug";   
    }
    if(val==09 || val==9)
    {
      val1="Sep";   
    }
    if(val==10)
    {
      val1="Oct";   
    }
    if(val==11)
    {
      val1="Nov";   
    }
    if(val==12)
    {
      val1="Dec";   
    }

    return val1;
}
```

where `freeLookEndDt = Sun Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2012`

Comment: u define newmonthName but use monthName, typo?

Comment: Here's your `convertMnthNoToName` function in 3 lines https://gist.github.com/3890921

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-javascript).

Comment: `var d = new Date(2012,8,30); b = new Date( 2012,8, d.getDate() + 1); b;` works fine for me, perhaps something is wrong with your `freeLookEndDt` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u define `newmonthName` but use `monthName`. Thus it is using old month name. `newmonthName`should have changed

you should just be able to do  `freeLookEndDt.setDate(freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1)`

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4RsMv/)

This is more efficient. Also you need to take the monthname AFTER you add the day

Please note your date in your example is resolving to Saturday in my country!!!

```
var monthNames ="Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".split(",")

if (freeLookEndDt.getDay()==0) {
  freeLookEndDt.setDate(freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1);  
  var dateMsg = freeLookEndDt.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[freeLookEndDt.getMonth()] + '-' + freeLookEndDt.getFullYear();
  document.forms[0].flEndDt.value=dateMsg;
}
```

or if you need to keep freeLookEndDate:

```
if (freeLookEndDt.getDay()==0) {
  var date = new Date(freeLookEndDt.getTime());
  date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);  
  var dateMsg = date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + '-' + date.getFullYear();
  document.forms[0].flEndDt.value=dateMsg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var date=new Date(freeLookEndDt.getFullYear(), freeLookEndDt.getMonth(),
                  freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1);
```

use

```
var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(freeLookEndDt.getFullYear());
date.setMonth(freeLookEndDt.getMonth());
date.setDate(freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1);
```

That way, you'll be setting day at the last step, and Date will recalculate stored month and year to correct values. Note that year also can change, if you have Dec.31.

Also, the function `convertMnthNoToName` can be modified to have more compact implementation and be able to handle also string input values, such as "03".

**Complete code:**

```
var monthName=convertMnthNoToName(freeLookEndDt.getMonth()+1);

if (freeLookEndDt.getDay()==0) {

    var date = new Date();
    date.setFullYear(freeLookEndDt.getFullYear());
    date.setMonth(freeLookEndDt.getMonth());
    date.setDate(freeLookEndDt.getDate()+1);
    var newmonthName=convertMnthNoToName(date.getMonth()+1);
    var dateMsg = date.getDate() + '-' + newmonthName + '-' + freeLookEndDt.getFullYear();

    document.forms[0].flEndDt.value=dateMsg;
}

/**
 * Converts month (1-based) to its string representation
 * @param {Number|String} val    Month index (from 1-January to 12-December)
 * @return {String}    String representation of month or empty string for invalid input parameter
 */
function convertMnthNoToName(val)
{
    val = parseInt(val); // string "01" will be converted to 1
    if(val>=1 && val<=12)
    {
        var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        return monthNames[val-1];
    }
    return "";
}
```